# ASP.NET Core 3 MVC Route Debugging

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1

What methods are available for debugging routing issues in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API? Specifically, the infamous 404.

I've seen tons of questions regarding this in a Web API but they all deal with the specific problems of the individual. What I am looking for is a systematic way of determining how/why my url matched or failed to match each route in the route collection.

Unfortunately, the logging output, even when set to Trace, only shows:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:5000/Ctrlr/Action  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 8.4141ms 404
```

Phil Haack's routedebugger for classic ASP.NET MVC was a wonderful tool but I don't believe that it can be used in .NET Core 3.

I feel like I'm missing something huge but I have looked without success.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know routedebugger. What are the useful information you'd like? The name of the route chosen? What information do you want when no route match?

Answer (score 0):

I the meanwhile there is an inspired github repo for this:

https://github.com/EdiWang/Edi.RouteDebugger

But like the old routedebugger you see only implemented routes.